# jQuery sliding to remove div bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I wanted to practice some jQuery and to do it I thought I would make the animation that Jay-Z uses on his new album commercials, he has a bar over his name and it slides left while also disappearing. On top of that I wanted the text to fadeOut, fadeIn, and then fadeOut again to give it a flashing effect before it disappeared. Can someone help me with this :l, I got the layout done but the jQuery just wont work..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Magna Carta</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bar').delay(800).css('padding-left', 0+'px');
        $('#main p').fadeOut('slow' function(){
            $('#main p').fadeIn('slow' function(){
                $('#main p').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#main {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main p {
    font-family:Admisi Display SSi;
    font-size:64px;
}

#bar {
    padding-left:180px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    margin-top:87px;
    margin-left:61px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="main">
         <center>
             <div id="bar"></div>
         </center>
         <p>JAY-Z</p>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should fix your callbacks (you need a comma between 'slow' and function in your fadeOut and fadeIn: http://jsfiddle.net/BjBry/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the animate function here (before you were just setting the padding-left to 0, which happens immediately) and you have to fix your fadeOut and fadeIn callback functions:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bar').delay(800).animate({
            'padding-left':0
        }, 1000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            $('#bar').delay(800).css('padding-left', 0 + 'px');
            $('#main p').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('#main p').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    $('#main p').fadeOut('slow');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BjBry/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to jQuery. I don't know what I would do without people like you. Thank you again.